# Why is the objective object in my pyomo code have an unknown type 'generator'?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am creating an optimisation problem with a myriad of constraints using the pyomo library in Python, but I continue to get an error in my seemingly simple Objective definition, and don't understand why.

I am creating an abstract model, where the objective is minimising the cost `(ab_mdl.c)` times the power `(ab_mdl.x)` for each hour `(i)` and each resource `(j)`. Here is the objective function written below:

```
def TOU_rule(ab_mdl):
    return(summation(ab_mdl.c[i]*ab_mdl.x[j,i]) for i in ab_mdl.hours for j in ab_mdl.num_of_cars)

ab_mdl.cost_obj=Objective(rule=TOU_rule)
```

But, when I run the full code, I get this error:

> Cannot treat the value '.
>   at 0x21427670>' as a constant because it has unknown type 'generator'

I don't understand what exactly is wrong with the code, especially since this is relatively simple objective, and I have followed the syntax of similar examples I've seen using Pyomo.  Does anyone have any ideas of what I should do next?

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is a typo in your question, but if it is not, I see 3 improvements that you should do to make your code work.

1. The `return(thing)` statement should be written `return thing`. That is because `return` is a separated word and there is no use for a parenthesis.
2. In the same line, `summation` is not the right word, you have to use `sum`.
3. Don't forget to put an optimization sense (`maximize` or `minimize`) when calling to build your objective.

Then, your code will be:

```
def TOU_rule(ab_mdl): 
    return sum(ab_mdl.c[i]*ab_mdl.x[j,i]) for i in ab_mdl.hours for j in ab_mdl.num_of_cars
ab_mdl.cost_obj=Objective(rule=TOU_rule, sense=minimize)
```

Comment: sorry, i was using sum, not summation (that was old code i didnt delete, sorry).  I changed it to the spaces, but now I get a separate error: that my Param value c[1] is undefined.  will look into the dict i used to create_instance. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I edited my answer while reviewing my own code. There's a new point. Sorry to hear for your undefined param value. I can tell you for sure this has nothing to do with the problem you mentionned. It is one of the most comon errors, and it tells you that your data is insuficient, or the parameters domain (sets) is to wide. Only you can find out. Good luck.

Comment: I also solved the other issue too.  When setting up ab_mdl.c as a Param, i set the within=PostiveReals, but then set c[1] =0.  So instead needed to change ab_mdl.c=Param(ab.Index,within=NonNegativeReals)